# How to switch the initial toggle condition from day to night?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Help me, how to switch the initial toggle button condition from day to night?

```css
/*
F5EB42 - sun inner
E4C74D - sun outer
FFFFFF - cloud inner
D4D4D2 - cloud outer
81C0D5 - parent outer
C0E6F6 - parent inner
FFFDF2 - moon inner
DEE1C5 - moon outer
FCFCFC - stars
*/
body {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.toggle:before,
.toggle:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.toggle:after {
  clear: both;
}

.toggle-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #C0E6F6;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #81C0D5;
  transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.toggle-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle-switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #F5EB42;
  border: 4px solid #E4C74D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.toggle-switch-figure {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 8px solid #D4D4D2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
          transform: scale(0.4);
  transition: all 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.toggle-switch-figure:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -65px;
  right: -42px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 8px solid #D4D4D2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(70deg);
          transform: rotateZ(70deg);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.toggle-switch-figure:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 8px solid #D4D4D2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg);
          transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.toggle-switch-figureAlt {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #EFEEDA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #DEE1C5;
  box-shadow: 42px -7px 0 -3px #FCFCFC, 75px -10px 0 -3px #FCFCFC, 54px 4px 0 -4px #FCFCFC, 83px 7px 0 -2px #FCFCFC, 63px 18px 0 -4px #FCFCFC, 44px 28px 0 -2px #FCFCFC, 78px 23px 0 -3px #FCFCFC;
  transition: all 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}

.toggle-switch-figureAlt:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 18px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #EFEEDA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #DEE1C5;
}

.toggle-switch-figureAlt:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #EFEEDA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #DEE1C5;
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ .toggle-switch {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-color: #DEE1C5;
  background-color: #FFFDF2;
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ .toggle-bg {
  background-color: #484848;
  border-color: #202020;
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ .toggle-switch .toggle-switch-figure {
  margin-left: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
          transform: scale(0.1);
}

.toggle-input:checked ~ .toggle-switch .toggle-switch-figureAlt {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="toggle">
    <input class="toggle-input" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="toggle-bg"></div>
    <div class="toggle-switch">
      <div class="toggle-switch-figure"></div>
      <div class="toggle-switch-figureAlt"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

should I change "before" and "after" in some cases? or...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the checked attribute to input

```
<input checked class="toggle-input" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change the input tag and set the checked attribute to false. It will work then. Always better to use the checked attribute of the input when you are defining the initial behavior of the component

```
<input class="toggle-input" type="checkbox" checked="false"/>
```